# Visual Studio Crashing in SSAS while trying to add a Rol to my OLAP Cube

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

As stated in the title Visual Studio crashes when i try to add a role to my cube. The deployment is successfull and everything goes fine concerning the cube functionalities. 
What I do is going to the roles section of the cube in Visual studio and right click New Role. At this point I select all the rights that I want and then when I click Add.. in the Membership tab to select the user the application crashes.
I hope i was clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem updating the Microsoft Analysis Services Projects reference in VS

Comment: Please describe how to do this. … … Do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.